# Error while installing Django on Mac

Tags: python, django

This is the error I'm getting

> Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory? 
>   If the installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may
>   need to sign in as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not
>   have administrative access to this machine, you may wish to choose a
>   different installation directory, preferably one that is listed in
>   your PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Even though my privileges are set to read and write.
I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

How are you installing Django? Did you create a virtualenv?

Comment: Take a look at this guide: [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/09/04/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-1.html)

Comment: Thanks it was a great help